# Knockout Dropdown (selectbox) value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am new to knockout and have been playing with the Cart example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html)

How would I go about assigning the value of the product dropdown on each line?. I want to be able to select the value of the selected item using JQuery and retain all the cart functionality.
The code that is rendered is as follows:

```
<td>
  <select class="form-control prodName" data-bind="options: $root.sampleProducts, optionsText: "name" , optionsCaption: "Select...", value: product">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="">Standard (sandwich)  </option>
    <option value="">Premium (lobster)</option>
    <option value="">Ultimate (whole zebra)</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

No value??... But I want:

```
  <td>
   <select class="form-control prodName" data-bind="options: $root.sampleProducts, optionsText: "name" , optionsCaption: "Select...", value: product">
    <option value="">Select...</option>　　　　　
    <option value="1">Standard (sandwich)</option>　　　　　
    <option value="2">Premium (lobster)</option>　　　　　
    <option value="3">Ultimate (whole zebra)</option>　　　　　
  </select>
</td>
```

The values are rendered, I have used optionsValue but that just causes the cart to break..

Comment: consider marking it answer which can be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding `optionsValue` to the `select` which makes `value` binding of dropdown to store `optionsValue` instead of selected dropdown object([value,text]) which was happening prior if you are not using optionsValue .

So you need to modify viewModel accordingly

**viewModel:**

```
self.subtotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.product() ? self.product() * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0; //self.product has price
    });
```

**view:**

```
<td class='price' data-bind='with: product'>
  <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency($data)'> </span> //use $data 
</td>
```

working sample with complete code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/4382/)**

Comment: Super cool that is almost what I need however (sorry I should have been more clear with my question), if the products objects contained an 'id' so the object would be {id: 1, name: 'name', price: '5.00'} how do i get the id into the value tag?

Comment: when you use optionsText:'price' & optionsValue:'id' you should get id into value binded observable . hope that helps

Comment: Na that still doesn't work.. I still want to have the name as the optionsText...when I try the price doesn't show up at all and the sub total only adds the id together therefore breaking the cart.. The id value is showing in the value tag though.. but that is because optionsValue..

Comment: now i see it i misread your initial comment . as you can have only one thing in `value` either id or price . keeping `id` in value tag which in turn used for calculation doesnt make sense . best way is not to use optionsValue and allow `value` binding to have object and you can use that further .

Comment: there is a alternative as you have `id` in value & `name` in text now you need to query observableArray with `id` to get the price and do the calculation . cheers

Comment: Could you please show what you said above in the update fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/4388/)here

Answer (score 0):

After trying about 20000 different ways, and reading through the knockout documentation may times, I ended up just adding a new column and getting setting the id value in that (not really a suitable solution but a solution never the less). If I used optionValue in any way it always broke, I did have success in updating the price field with a custom function but that in turn broke the subtotal and grandtotal functionality. The working fiddle is at this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/4459/) if anyone is interested... a snip of the html is below:

`<tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="mySel" data-bind='options: $root.sampleProducts, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: product'> </select>
                </td>
                <td class='id' data-bind='with: product'>
                    <span data-bind='text: $parent.getId($data)'></span>
                </td>
                <td class='price' data-bind='with: product'>
                    <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(price)'> </span>
                </td>
                <td class='quantity'>
                    <input data-bind='value: quantity, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
                </td>
                <td class='price'>
                    <input data-bind='value: formatCurrency(subtotal())' />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>`